# Getting Error When Trying TO Update URL keys in magento with PHP script

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to update the URL keys in magento, to set the URL keys as the same as the name of product. I have tried using the following script which I found online.

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$amount = 0;
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$products = $model->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $model->load($product->getId());
    $product->setUrlKey($model->getName())->save();
    set_time_limit();
    $amount++;
}
?>
```

However, I am presented with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on a non-object in 
/home/replaysp/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configu
rable.php on line 404
```

This is the line of code that this error points too:

```
$this->getProduct($product)->setData($attribute->getProductAttribute()
    ->getAttributeCode(), null);
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works (disclaimer: not tested):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$products= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $model->load($product->getId());
    $product->setUrlKey($model->getName());
    $product->getResource()->save($product);
    set_time_limit();
    $amount++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That code gives an error which says class 'Mage' not found on line 2... any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Omg. Include this at the beginning of the code require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

Comment: Proposed solution works great but there's a missing semi-colon on line 6.

Comment: @epingle thanks for pointing-out! I fixed the missing semi-colon on line 6.